How to use oracle oud in go-lang
I'm fairly new to go-lang and trying to figure out on how can we connect to Oracle OUD from go-lang. So far we've been using Oracle TNS file and instant client via go-lang's oci8.Below is the code being used. How can this code be leveraged to use Oracle OUD(Oracle Unified directory).
import (
    "configurations"
    "utils"
    "database/sql"
    "log"
 )

var db *sql.DB

func init() {
    configs := configurations.conf(utils.CONFIG_FILE,true)
    GetDbConn(configs.DBConnection)
}

func GetDbConn(DBConnection string) {
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("oci8", DBConnection) //goracle oci8

    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}

 func CloseDbConn(db *sql.DB) {
    db.Close()
}

Downloaded go-dror package and trying different options to understand on how the existing code can be leveraged to Oracle OUD
